# envoyproxy: what is the pattern for adding a service/sidecar as new endpoint?

Tags: envoyproxy

In envoyproxy, when you start up a new service/sidecar instance(service mesh+horizontal scaling), how do you announce/join the instance as a new cluster endpoint?

All the examples seem to be about receiving configuration from xDS(i.e get clusters/listeners etc) - how does a new instance add itself to the set of cluster endpoints?

Is this meant to be done out-of-band(from envoyproxy POV) using Consul/other xDS server(go-control-plane, java-control-plane) - and these xDS servers are supposed to have their own separate "joining/announcement" API?

IOW, I am looking for the opposite of 'service discovery' - 'service announcement' aka 'service-reporting-for-work'.